# xamarin Error : Popover segue with no anchor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, segue

I am trying to use Xamarin in VisualStudio for developing iOS application. I added manual Segue in StoryBoard,  selected show segue. But then I see it null.Following image:

[image]

And Error:[image]

How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Xamarin 4.3.0.237 (alpha)

To update go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other > and change to alpha to download

Remember to also update Xamarin on Mac for it to work

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same problems. I've been fixing it by manually opening up the storyboard file and modifying the xml, adding in the anchor.

```
<segue id="4154" destination="4110" kind="popover" popoverAnchorView="1904">
    <popoverArrowDirection key="popoverArrowDirection" up="YES" down="YES" left="YES" right="YES"/>
</segue>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this is a bug in Xamarin.
Its already reported over here: [Link to Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46562)